# Step in the motivation of Lax-Milgram with membrane problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

My notes motivate Lax-Milgram theorem by using the membrane problem.

We take $E[u] = \int_{\Omega} \Big(\frac \sigma 2|\nabla u|^2+\frac \alpha 2u^2-f(x)u\Big)dx$ the functional associated to the problem and we make variations on it. So we define $g(s) = E[u+s\phi]$ with $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $u$ a potential minimum of $E$. Then $g'(0) = 0$ and $\int_{\Omega} (\sigma \nabla u \nabla \phi + \alpha u \phi - f \phi) dx = 0$. Then, my notes claim that $\int_{\Omega} (- \Delta u +\alpha v -f)\phi dx = 0$.

I don't understand this last equality. I have tried to do it with integration by parts. But if I write $\nabla u \nabla \phi = \frac{du}{dt}\frac{d\phi}{dt}+\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d\phi}{dx}$ the argument works well with the second part but for the first part I have to integrate $\int \frac{d\phi}{dt}dx$ and I get the derivative $\frac{du}{dxdt}$ not a addend of the laplacian.

**When does the integration make sense?**

As suggested by @Uskebasi, I was not integrating with respect to $t$.

Now my question is, do I have to impose anything to $\Omega$ so that the integration makes sense?

I treated a general setting where $\Omega$ was a bounded and "regular" domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (this is the case my notes seem to refer) and a more specific case where $x \in  [0,L]$ and $t \in [0,\infty[$. In this case I wonder if the integration still makes sense.

Comment: Are you sure there is no integration in the $t$ variable? As stated $E$ is a function of $t$

Comment: Are you working with a fixed $t$? Otherwise, how do you make the variation on $E$? With your definition of $E$, $E=E[u](t)$. This seems odd to me

Comment: @Uskebasi rereading my notes, it seems that this is the functional assuming equilibrium so $u(t,x) = u(x)$

Comment: If you're working in the case $u(x,t)=u(x)$, with an integration by parts you should get the result, because now $\nabla u \nabla \phi$ reduces to $u'\phi'$ and you don't have the problem with the $t$ derivative.

Comment: Anyway, you can do it even for a $u$ which depends on $t$ if you follow the classical approach outlined in the answer below, but in this case you obtain a pde with a term of the form $u_{t}$ (or maybe $u_{tt}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time-dependent problems, it really depends on how you define your functional $E$. There seems to have two different approaches: the classical approach where you treat space and time separately, and the modern approach where you treat space-time as a whole.

For the classical approach, your functional $E$ is no longer the potential energy, but action instead. Take your membrane $u=u(t,x)$ for instance. Its total potential energy reads
$$
E_p[u]=\int_{x\in\left[0,L\right]}\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}\left|u\right|^2-fu\right){\rm d}x,
$$
whereas its kinetic energy reads
$$
E_k[u]=\int_{x\in\left[0,L\right]}\frac{\rho}{2}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right|^2{\rm d}x,
$$
where $\rho$ stands for the surface mass density of this membrane. Obviously, this kinetic energy expression is exactly in analogy with $\left(1/2\right)mv^2$.

Now, there is a [principle of least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) in classical physics, stating that the physically true behavior of $u$ is such that the time integral of the kinetic energy **minus** the total potential is stationary, i.e.,
$$
J[u]=\int_{t\in\left[0,\infty\right)}\left(E_k[u]-E_p[u]\right){\rm d}t
$$
is locally minimized. Thus in this approach, you need to make use of this $J$ instead of $E$, and Lax-Milgram would lead to
$$
\left(\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}s}J[u+s\phi]\right)\Bigg|_{s=0}=0.
$$
You may check that this yields the desired
$$
\rho\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\sigma\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\alpha u+f.
$$

Alternatively, you may choose the modern approach by treating $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ as
$$
\left(t,x\right)\in\Omega=\left[0,\infty\right)\times\left[0,L\right].
$$
You may also put the coordinate as $\left(x,t\right)$. The order of time $t$ and space $x$ in the tuple does not make any difference. In this case, however, you should be very careful about the definition of a "vector" in space-time. You need to adopt the Lorentz metric instead of the standard Euclidean metric, i.e.,
$$
\left\|\left(T,X\right)\right\|^2=-T^2+X^2,
$$
or in the three-dimensional-space case,
$$
\left\|\left(T,X,Y,Z\right)\right\|^2=-T^2+X^2+Y^2+Z^2.
$$
You may put $c$, the speed of light, in front of $T$ as well; mathematically the expressions read the same up to a coupling constant.

Now, get back to your problem, and
$$
\nabla u:=\left(\sqrt{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t},\sqrt{\sigma}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)
$$
becomes a "vector" in your space-time (with only one dimension in space). In this case, you could similarly define 
$$
I[u]=\int_{\Omega}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left\|\nabla u\right\|^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}u^2-fu\right){\rm d}V,
$$
where the norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ follows the definition of Lorentz metric.

You could check that
$$
I[u]=-J[u],
$$
for which these two approaches are somewhat equivalent. Nevertheless, as time gets involved, it would be hard to say if the functional is minimized or maximized. And this is why I put it in above as that this functional is *stationary*.

Comment: thanks, this is really clarifying. if you have any recommendation for reading about this it would be great

Comment: @Javier: You may google "principle of least action", and any textbook-level notes would do, like [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/LeastAction.pdf). The key part is to understand how $\int_{t\in\left[t_1,t_2\right]}\left[\left(1/2\right)m\dot{x}^2-\Phi(x)\right]{\rm d}t$ leads to Newton's second law $m\ddot{x}=-\nabla\Phi(x)$. This is more about physics than mathematics. For the mathematical part, any reference related to [calculus of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) would do, e.g., see [this](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387402475).